# Modelling soil texture using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-conversion, modelling

I am doing a project for automated soil mapping using landsat TM imagery,
I have 3 output rasters: one for sand percentage one for silt percentage and a third for clay percentage.

How can I incorporate these three rasters to get an output raster where pixels are classified on the basis of percent silt sand and clay according to USDA soil textural triangle?

I want my model to symbolize it on the go, for example green represents silty loam in my map etc.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and want to do the work in a form of model.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141415

Answer (score 2):

If you go to this [site](http://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/survey/?cid=nrcs142p2_054167) (I did nothing more than a simple Google search) there is an online calculator. Right at the top is a link to an Excel file this appears to contain all the logic you require to compute your soil texture type. I would suggest you look there first as all you need to do is transfer that logic to a python/model environment.

As for symbolizing it you could create a pre-built layer file with the appropriate symbology set and you *apply* that to the final dataset.